# Add filters to a Child of a Parent within the View.py

Tags: python, django

I have a Parent `(companies)` with many children `(charges)`; with this data, I am listing individual companies with associated charges on a table.  All works well (see code below)

However, I want to add filters to the `charges` in view.py; I know I can do this via the template using template conditions, but am finding this limited and cumbersome.  For example, I can't find a distinct template condition, and I have to pile through several `if` conditions for other things, making everything a tad cumbersome when it would be easier if I could do so in view.py

Is there a way of adding a filter to the child records as associated with its parent.  So `Company A` has 5 associated `charges` which I want to filter by date (as an example) - again, I know this can be done via template conditions, but I'm wondering if it can be done in the view

Hope that makes sense!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from companies.models import Company, Charge, Filing
from django.http import HttpResponse

def watch_list(request):
    companies = Company.objects.order_by('-data_date')

    return render(request,'company_watch/watch_list.html',{'companies':companies})
```

---

```
{% for company in companies %}
<tr>
   <td>{{company.name}}</td>
   <td>
      <ul>
         {% for charge in company.charge_set.all %}
         <li>{{charge.charge_id}}</li>
         {% endfor %}
      </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The solution depends on your exact need. Is the condition always the same or dynamic?

Comment: It would be the same condition throughout

Comment: Then it might make sense to add a method to the `Company` model that returns the `Charge`s that satisfy the condition.

Comment: A model method?  That makes sense - I will give it a go; I'm just surprised it can't be worked into the view.py, but learning as I go.

Comment: You _can_ do it in the view, but that requires you to eagerly compute all companies and all charges in advance, and storing them into a different data structure (such as a dictionary). A model method lets you lazily perform the extra query when/if requested by the template. There might be some logic in the template, for example, to skip some companies depending on a criteria. In such a case you won't want to query the charges for those skipped companies.